# Woocomerce logout link

Tags: woocommerce, hyperlink, logout, account

I am trying to add an icon button to logout of wordpress woocommerce account but the link that is in woccommerce dashboard Log out keeps changing every-time the page refreshes so coping the link on my account not you log out doesn't work. Any one able to help in how I can achieve this?

I have tried from google searches but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.